# RAM memory is increasing progressively

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I'm having some issues with my VPS Ve, right now I have two sites running with PHP (one of them with Wordpress), a few days ago the RAM usage rose above 100%, strange thing is I made no changes.

RAM memory is increasing progressively in the MediaTemple statics panel, what I don't understand is why do I have so much difference between the data I get from the console.

My Setup:

> - nginx
> - php-fpm
> - apc
> - mysql
> - Ubuntu 10.04
> - 4GB RAM (VPS)

**htop:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENlUA.png

**Free -m:**

```
total      used    free  shared buffers  cached
Mem:       6348    2854    3494    0       0       2403
-/+ buffers/cache:   450       5897
Swap:    0     0       0
```

Could you guide me so I may know what is it that is using up memory?

Thanks!

Comment: Is something actually wrong or is this just curiosity.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
My only problem is that MT statics are showing that I'm consuming more than 110% of memory. And I'm worried that it might be something I could be penalized for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's cache, don't worry, it's normal and it's good:

http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Your system is "using" 450 MB of RAM :)
Cache will be flushed and applications will be able to use freed memory when needed. Why to waste memory? Let's use it for cache.

[Here's good script for you](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py)

Comment: I installed the script that you gave me, thanks, result threw 501.5MB which is a lot lower than the 4GB that what my hosting provider is showing. 

I don't get why RAM memory statistics on the server keep rising progressively until they're over 110%. Thanks!! :D